# Kivy password check

Tags: python, kivy

Newbie to kivy, i want to look a username and pass in db, but currently i tried to check my own "logins". I get:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fbind'

when i run app. What's wrong?

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main_grid = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10)
        main_box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',padding = 25)# Основной лэйаут.

        main_box.add_widget(Label(text='Login'))
        self.username = TextInput(text='',multiline=False,size_hint_y=None) # Обьявление логина
        main_box.add_widget(self.username)
        main_box.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(text='', password=True, multiline=False, size_hint_y=None) # Обьявление пароля
        main_box.add_widget(self.password)
        main_box.add_widget(main_grid)

        main_grid.add_widget(Widget())
        main_grid.add_widget(Button(text='Войти',on_press=self.login))
        return main_box

    def login(self, instance):
        print(self.username.text)
        print(self.password.text)
        if self.username.text == 'admin':
            if self.password.text == 'password':
                popup = Popup(title='Logged',content='Logged in successfully, admin')
                popup.open()
            else:
                popup = Popup(title='Wrong password',content='Wrong password, admin. Go away.')
                popup.open()
        elif self.username.text == 'user':
            if self.password.text == 'userpass':
                popup = Popup(title='Logged',content='Logged in successfully, user')
                popup.open()
            else:
                popup = Popup(title='Wrong password',content='Wrong password, user. Go away.')
                popup.open()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, is that the only code you are using?

Comment: @eyllanesc u need imports?

Comment: no, I have executed your code, I have added the imports and it works correctly, so I say I can not reproduce your problem. What version of kivy are you using?

Comment: @eyllanesc, try to input in first form "admin" and in second one "password". Without quotes

Comment: try my answer, if this served you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it review the [tour], that is the best way to thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because the Popup content waits for a widget to show but you are passing it a string, so the solution is to replace it for example by a Label.

```
def login(self, instance):
    print(self.username.text)
    print(self.password.text)
    if self.username.text == 'admin':
        if self.password.text == 'password':
            popup = Popup(title='Logged',content=Label(text='Logged in successfully, admin'))
            popup.open()
        else:
            popup = Popup(title='Wrong password',content=Label(text='Wrong password, admin. Go away.'))
            popup.open()
    elif self.username.text == 'user':
        if self.password.text == 'userpass':
            popup = Popup(title='Logged',content=Label(text='Logged in successfully, user'))
            popup.open()
        else:
            popup = Popup(title='Wrong password',content=Label(text='Wrong password, user. Go away.'))
            popup.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using StringProperty to maintain the text of the Textbox.

```
self.usertext = StringProperty()
def on_text(self,text)
    self.usertext = text

textinput = TextInput()
textinput.bind(text = lambda x: on_text(x,x.text))
```